# EWS managed API: Is user A able to impersonate User B in a windows app?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I need to determine whether domain UserA -- currently running a Windows desktop application -- has permissions to impersonate another user in Exchange, say UserB.

I can try to do something like read UserB's inbox messages, but I was after a cleaner way to do it.

Is there no way to load the UserA's Exchange roles and look for ApplicationImpersonation or something else?

So the setup is like this:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl(userEmail);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, UserToImpersonate);
```

// Looking for something like this:

if (!service.CanImpersonate(userEmail, UserToImpersonate) )
{
    Exception ex = new Exception(userEmail + " can't impersonate " + UserToImpersonate);
    throw ex;
}

Answer (score 0):

Not using EWS you would need to use the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/role-based-access-control/get-managementroleassignment?view=exchange-ps to check if applicationimpersonation is enable for a particular user. EWS is a Mailbox API and the setting your talking about is an administrative setting so the best you can do with EWS is deal with the exception and suggest corrective action.